# NotImplementedError: Evaluating a LinearExpr instance as a Boolean is not implemented

Tags: python, or-tools

I want to check the shift count for each day for particular employee during algorithm execution but as because of boolean, I cannot.
I am trying something like :

```py
for e in self.all_employees:
    for sd in start_day:
        if self.employee_leaves[(e,sd)] == 1:
            sum1 = sum(self.shifts[e,sd,s] for s in self.all_shifts)
```

```
NotImplementedError: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpression '((shift_n0d14s0 + shift_n0d14s1) + shift_n0d14s2) == 0' as a Boolean value is not supported.
```

Comment: I think this is not enough code to see the error. What does `self.shifts` contains? Are you using a third-party library?

Comment: self.shifts[emp_no, day_no, shift_no], not using any third-party library , its google or tools only.

Answer (score 2):

So, there are multiple misconceptions here.

Variables are opaque objects. They have no integer value. During search, the solver will try to find an assignment variable -> integer value that represent a feasible/optimal solution. But this assignment will be stored in the solver, and can be queried there once the solver exits search.

Then, var == 1 actually creates an object. In order for this not to always be silently evaluated to true, I have added this message telling you that you cannot write this test.

Comment: Yes, Here I have written this as this is in my mind and i want to apply this as my logic, how will I do it? How will I get the sum ?

Comment: can you write the math equation you want to implement, without any imperative programming ?

Comment: **if employee_leaves[(empno,current_startday)] ==1:** # 1->working, 0-> on leave
            # check in algorithm on d day was that employee working or not working 
            **if self.shifts[e,d,s] ==0:** #[here is something i want to do. which i cant bcz of implementing google or tools]
                **reservedforce_count +=1
        else:
            reservedforce_count +=1**

Comment: this is imperative programming. You cannot check the value of a variable,  nor use if.

Comment: exactly thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

A addendum to the (correct) answer; if you came here, like me because you had the same error message, but a different scenario like this one:

```
exprVariable = None
exprVariable = create_variable()
if exprVariable:
    do_something()
```

The correct syntax is:

```
if exprVariable is not None:
    do_something()
```